# How to scrape non restful API using python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, data-mining

Am trying to scrape this [website](https://tncovidbeds.tnega.org/). I found out from the Network tab of Google Developer Tools that a request named **hospitals** to the URL https://tncovidbeds.tnega.org/api/hospitals had the response I need.

I tried recreating the same situation with the same headers and payload in my python code but am getting a response different from that from the website.

Here is my python code :

```
import requests

url = r'https://tncovidbeds.tnega.org/api/hospitals'

d = {
"searchString":"",
"sortCondition":{"Name":1},
"pageNumber":1,
"pageLimit":10,
"SortValue":"Availability",
"Districts":["5ea0abd3d43ec2250a483a4f"],
"BrowserId":"b4c5b065a84c7d2b60e8b23d415b2c3a",
"IsGovernmentHospital":"true",
"IsPrivateHospital":"true",
"FacilityTypes":["CHO","CHC","CCC"]
}

h = {
"authority": "tncovidbeds.tnega.org",
"method": "POST",
"path":"/api/hospitals",
"scheme": "https",
"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"content-length": "280",
"content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
"cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.1066740172.1620653373; _gid=GA1.2.1460220464.1620653373",
"origin": "https://tncovidbeds.tnega.org",
"pragma": "no-cache",
"sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
"sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
"sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
"sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
"sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
"token": "null",
}

res = requests.post(url, data=d, headers=h)
print(res.json())
```

The output I got is :

```
{
'result': None,
 'exception': '',
 'pagination': None,
 'statusCode': '500',
 'errors': [],
 'warnings': []
}
```

The response I need and the one from networks tab of Google is :

```
{
"result": A BIG LIST OF JSON OBJECTS,
"exception":null,
"pagination":{"pageNumber":1,"pageLimit":10,"skipCount":0,"totalCount":155},
"statusCode":"200",
"errors":[],
"warnings":[]}
```

Can you please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get response Cannot GET /hospitals update your question?

Comment: If u copy paste the URL in a browser of course you'll get a blank page with no responses becoz a http request has to be sent to the URL with a JSON object to get a response. Just navigating to the path won't work. Answering to Gowtham Sooryaraj  in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your browser request the `content-type` must be `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. When passing a payload as a `data` parameter requests [will create](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#lower-level-classes) a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. To fix this you need to pass your payload as `json` argument. It will set the correct `content-type` automatically:

```py
requests.post(url, json=d)
```

Also in your case you don't need to provide any additional headers for the request to work.